# PhoneGap disable iPad support

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova

I would like to have only iPhone support for my application.

As far as I can see from [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_pgb_config.md.html), one can set `handset` option in `target-device`:

```
<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
```

But this however does not work. After the build (I build application locally on the machine), I see `Devices` is set to `Universal` in the `Deployment Info` of the project.

How do I disable iPad support?

Comment: Select project navigator left side > Targets > Select Summary tab, there is one device drop down , select iPhone and click on validate settings button in bottom.

Comment: @Ved thanks, I know that. I am interested how to change this in the PhoneGap configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was added in cordova-lib-0.21.8-dev according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7118 which has been resolved. I've tested with cordova 4.2.0 and it appears to be working correctly.

Comment: Instead of adding link, better to provide source code snippet here